# Web scraping an xml page in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am confused as to how I would scrape all the links (that only contain the string "mp3") off a given xml page. The following code only returns empty brackets:

```
# Import required modules 
from lxml import html 
import requests 
  
# Request the page 
page = requests.get('https://feeds.megaphone.fm/darknetdiaries') 
  
# Parsing the page 
# (We need to use page.content rather than  
# page.text because html.fromstring implicitly 
# expects bytes as input.) 
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)   
  
# Get element using XPath 
buyers = tree.xpath('//enclosure[@url="mp3"]/text()') 
print(buyers)
```

Am I using @url wrong?

The links I am looking for:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What happens?

The following `xpath` wont work, as you mentioned it is the use of `@url` and also `text()`

```
//enclosure[@url="mp3"]/text()
```

### Solution

The attribute `url` in any `//enclosure` should contain `mp3` and then returned `/@url`

Change this line:

```
buyers = tree.xpath('//enclosure[@url="mp3"]/text()')
```

to

```
buyers = tree.xpath('//enclosure[contains(@url,"mp3")]/@url')
```

**Output**

```
['https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV9231072845.mp3?updated=1610644901',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV2643452814.mp3?updated=1609788944',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV5381316822.mp3?updated=1607279433',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV9145504181.mp3?updated=1607280708',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV4345070838.mp3?updated=1606110384',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV8112097820.mp3?updated=1604866665',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV2164178070.mp3?updated=1603781321',
 'https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/traffic.megaphone.fm/ADV1107638673.mp3?updated=1610220449',
...]
```

Comment: Sorry about that! Was doing some testing with another page and forgot to update the link in the original code again. Your code works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does not directly answer your question, but you could check out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as an alternative (and it has an option to use `lxml` under the hoop too).

```py
import lxml # early failure if not installed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
  
# Request the page 
page = requests.get('https://feeds.megaphone.fm/darknetdiaries') 

# Parse
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

# Find
#mp3 = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a') if 'mp3' in link['href']]
# UPDATE - correct tag and attribute
mp3 = [link['url'] for link in soup.find_all('enclosure') if 'mp3' in link['url']]
```

Comment: Note that my answer has a bug in it because I do not know the structure of the `xml`. I simply assume that all the links you are intending are enclosed in a `<a>` and that when you say `mp3` you are talking about inside the `href` attribute.

Comment: Fixed the question to include what I was looking for in more detail.

Comment: Also, I had tried to get BeautifulSoup to work but I couldn't. I felt like I was doing everything right but I would never get a table of information. Might be that I'm using VSCode? In the answer above I was able to get the code to work, but I am also very interested to learn BeautifulSoup as it looks very powerful! Thank you for the time you put into my question!

Comment: Updated it with the correct tag and attribute as per your update.

Likely you just need to read through the docs and play around with it interactively.